# Unable to call a method TS function from NbMenuItem

Tags: angular, nebular

I am need to call a TS function which basically does some stuff like open a new tab/window with some URL from the NbMenuItem item. I am not able to find the property(like we have url/target/title/etc) which can help me link the function with the item.

Here is the items list I have created:

```
items: NbMenuItem[] = [
    {
      title: 'Home page',
      link: '/home',
      home: true,
      icon: { icon: 'dashboard', pack: 'icon-pack' },
      hidden: this.homePageMenuItemCheck(),
    },
    {
      title: 'Cost Calculator',
      expanded: false,
      icon: 'calculator',
      hidden: this.costCalculatorPageMenuItemCheck(),
      children: [
        {
          title: 'test1',
          //here I wish to call this TS function showPopUp()
        },
        {
          title: 'test2',
          url: 'https://www.google.com',
          target: '_blank'
        }
      ]      
    }
   ];
```

I am totally clueless how to get this done. Would really appreciate help in this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try injecting nbmenuservice by doing as follows:

```
 constructor(
private _nbMenuService: NbMenuService)


 ngOnInit() {
this._nbMenuService.onItemClick().subscribe((event) => {
  if (event.item.title === 'test1') {
   // Do whatever you want
  }
});
```

}

i hope this would help you!